# How to install the QField Sync plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, qfield

I am having trouble installing the QField Sync plugin to work with the great QField android app. and would like assistance doing so. The steps I have followed thus far are reproduced below.
(Using QGIS 2.18 via OSGEO4w installer on Windows 7)

When I attempt to install it through the Plugin Manager I get an error message telling me to install the "QGIS2compat" plugin:

[image: Failed to install QField Sync plugin]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5tIP.png

I select "uninstall" plugin from this dialog.

Then I install the "QGIS2compat" plugin which seems to work properly:

[image: Succesfully installed "QGIS2compat" plugin]

However if I then attempt to install the "QField Sync" plugin afterwards (without restarting) I get the following message:

[image: QField Sync Error Message_02]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzcI2.png

So I uninstall and, after restarting QGIS (having installed "QGIS2compat" and not "QField Sync") and before QGIS loads fully I get the following error message and "Processing Toolbox" is disabled:

[image: Processing UIC Error Message 01]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JzBD.png

When I try to install the "QField Sync" plugin now, I get the same "UIC" error message as above but I leave it installed anyway and the Plugin Manager tells me that it is "broken" - I also can't find it in any of the Plugin panels/toolbars.

[image: QField Installed though broken_01]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0urTm.png

So I restart QGIS and get the following error messages in the Log from start up:

[image: QGIS start Error messages Log 01]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySQzx.png

So I uninstall "QGIS2compat", restart QGIS, the "Processing toolbox" returns but I still have no "QFIELD Sync".

Can anyone help me to install "QField Sync" properly?

[EDIT: Further to the above, now using QGIS version 2.18.11 win7, following similar steps to above, I get the following error:

[image: QField Sync Error Message_02]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dz7h.png]

Comment: Same issue here on Linux. qgis2compat seems to be a work in progress.

Comment: Would @MatthiasKuhn have any idea?

Comment: Works for me using QGIS 2.18.0 standalone installer for Windows 7 64-bit. Repeated your steps: Installed `QField` but received an error suggesting to install `qgis2compat` first. I then selected _Uninstall_ from dialog and installed `qgis2compat` Then installed `QField` successfully. All of this without restarting QGIS. You could try downloading/installing QGIS 2.18.1 standalone and see if that works?

Comment: Well thank you @Joseph ... I have just updated to 2.18.1 (using osgeo4w) and it worked a treat, installed without any of the errors listed above! **I am very grateful!** ... I think the plugin may have been updated also: My Plugin Manager now says 'Available version: 0.8.7 (in QGIS Official Plugin Repository)' whereas the screenshots above say available version was '0.4' ... Perhaps MatthiasKuhn and the opengis.ch folks did hear the whispers?! You folks are so amazing!

Comment: @guestagain - Awesome, glad it works. Yes, could very well be that the updated plugin solved your issue. Consider posting your _comment_ as an **answer** ;)

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT: Unfortunately the answer/fix discussed below is no longer working and the same or similar circumstances to those described in the question above persist ... will re-edit if things change again]

This question/problem has now been answered/fixed!

Either one or both of updating to the latest version of QGIS (2.18.1 in this instance) as well as what seems to be an update to the version of the plugin I was having trouble with has resolved the issue.

At the time of the problem the QField Sync plugin was version `0.4` though the 'Available version ... (in QGIS Official Plugin Repository)' is now: `0.8.7`

Thanks to all the wonderful folks at QField (opengis.ch) and on GIS SE!

Comment: problem persists ... see edit to original question above

Comment: I installed qfield sync on QGIS 2.18.10 yesterday, got the same errors during installation, but now it works. Did you update qgis2compat as well?

Comment: hello @AndreJ, cheers, yeah, sorry, should have noted that, I did update qgis2compat as well. Both qgis2compat and QFieldSync plugins seem to install ok first time round, i.e. I used the QFieldSync to package a demo project during the same instance of runnning QGIS (i.e. without restarting QGIS). But when I do restart QGIS, I get 2 ~blocking dialogs on startup, one which says the refFunctions plugin can't operate etc. and the other saying Processing won't load (and it doesn't) ... then QGIS loads without these tools, as well as a series of other plugins disabled. hmmm

Comment: Perhaps you should remove all plugins, and re-add qgis2compat, Qfield, and the others one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with QGIS 2.18.24 and QfieldSync 1.0.0.
**BUT** if you :

- uninstall QFieldSync
- uninstall qgis2compat
- check the "show experimental extensions" checkbox in the QGIS's extensions parameters
- reinstall QfieldSync,

The problem disapears of its own.

You have installed the 1.1.3 version of QFieldSync, which doesn't need qgis2compat anymore, and works perfectly.