# "ImportError: cannot import name uic" error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, importerror

I've just updated to the current version (2.18.5 on Windows) of QGIS, in the hope of getting rid of the above error, without success. Some time ago I tried to install the QField Sync plugin, which I believe was the first time I saw this error.

One thing I notice is the weird file path `apps/qgis/./python\qgis`, it's got slashes going both ways and a dot in the middle! If you ignore the weirdness the path does exist though.

```
ImportError: cannot import name uic 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 29, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 31, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 42, in 
    from processing.script.ScriptUtils import ScriptUtils
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 30, in 
    from processing.script.ScriptAlgorithm import ScriptAlgorithm
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 34, in 
    from processing.gui.Help2Html import getHtmlFromHelpFile
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import uic
ImportError: cannot import name uic


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.5 Las Palmas, 140a01f 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/marcp/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/marcp/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/marcp/.qgis2//python
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes it is possible that some files from older installations aren't correctly replaced/deleted when updating to the newest QGIS version and you may get an error like the one that you reported.

For these cases, an option is trying to delete the `.qgis2` folder, which should be placed (in Windows) at this location:

```
C:\Users\account_name
```

where `account_name` is the name of your system account.

This folder will be automatically created at the next start of QGIS (remember to backup the custom scripts and models before deleting the `.qgis` folder, otherwise you will definitively lost them!).

Comment: After install `QFieldSync` and `QGIS2compat` in linux mint, then delete `.qgis` folder and restart `QGIS`, anything is OK.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error message: "cannot import name QtWidgets" when I tried to install "QFieldSync" plugin on a fresh install of QGIS 2.18.9 (on Windows 10).

I followed `@mgri`'s instructions and deleted the `.qgis2` folder (which persisted after the install).
I then installed the "QGIS2compat" plugin and then tried to install "QFieldSync" when I got the above error message.

I uninstalled "QFieldSync" and restarted QGIS (having looked at [related question 219245](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219245/how-to-install-the-qfield-sync-plugin)). 
I tried to install the "QFieldSync" plugin again, and this time got no error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue installing QField in QGIS 2.18.10 I tried; restarting and deleting .qgs folder (suggested in another post) but the issue persisted. The issue resolved itself when I used the OSGeo Installer to remove pyQT5, reinstall pyQT4 and the QScintilla. I have not yet tried to reinstall pyQT5 yet but the plugin now installs and seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error on Ubuntu Desktop running QGIS 2.18.16. This error occurred after I attempted to install QField Sync, which required the installation of QGIS2compat. when opening QGIS, I received the same error "cannot import name uic...". To resolve the issue, I uninstalled QGIS2compat and restarted QGIS. Upon restart, the error did not appear and the Processing tool and all other plugins (e.g. Profile Tool) work once again.